# Sometimes program can't write to opened file during server reboot process

Tags: c, linux, shell, signals, redhat

I have a working program which sometimes misbehave from what I thought.
The following code will open five files which are empty and already created, and data will be written as program executed.

for eg,
if executed command is

```
./program /tmp/test /tmp/reboot.sh
```

Then program will open following five already created empty files.

```
/tmp/test.start
/tmp/test.end
/tmp/test.ret
/tmp/test.stderr
/tmp/test.stdout
```

And then it will write some data to `/tmp/test.start`.

And it continue to execute a given shell script file by forking a child process.

And in the end, parent process is assumed to write some data to `/tmp/test.end` and `/tmp/test.ret` and exit.

This is working as expected. However, with following `reboot.sh` which is supplied as program parameter, parent rarely can't write data to `/tmp/test.end` and `/tmp/test.ret`.

This is happening rarely. I can't figured out this case.

One thing I am assuming is parent pid was killed before child is killed.

The OS is `RedHat 5.5`.

Any help would be really appreciated.

```
//program.c

#define SIZE 4096
const char *ext[] = { "start", "end", "ret", "stdout", "stderr", NULL };

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *filepath, *cmd;
    char fn[SIZE];
    int i;
    int fd, fd_start, fd_end, fd_ret, fd_stdout, fd_stderr;
    time_t now;
    pid_t pid;
    int ret;

    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s output_filepath command\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }
    filepath = argv[1];
    cmd = argv[2];
    ret = 127;

    fd = -1;
    fd_start = -1;
    fd_end = -1;
    fd_ret = -1;
    fd_stdout = -1;
    fd_stderr = -1;
    i = 0;
    while (ext[i] != NULL) {
        sprintf(fn, "%s.%s", filepath, ext[i]);
        fd = open(fn, O_WRONLY | O_BINARY | O_TRUNC);
        if (fd < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s\n", fn, strerror(errno));
            return -1;
        }
        if (i == 0)
            fd_start = fd;
        else if (i == 1)
            fd_end = fd;
        else if (i == 2)
            fd_ret = fd;
        else if (i == 3)
            fd_stdout = fd;
        else if (i == 4)
            fd_stderr = fd;
        else
            close(fd);
        i++;
    }

    fflush(stdout);
    fflush(stderr);
    dup2(fd_stdout, 1);
    dup2(fd_stderr, 2);

    now = time(NULL);
    if (write(fd_start, &now, sizeof(now)) < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "fd_start: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    close(fd_start);

    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "fork: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    if (pid == 0) {
            //some codes
        }
        execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", cmd, NULL);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s :%s\n", cmd, strerror(errno));
        exit(ret);
    }

    if (pid > 0)
        waitpid(pid, &ret, WUNTRACED);

    now = time(NULL);
    if (write(fd_end, &now, sizeof(now)) < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "fd_end: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    close(fd_end);

    if (write(fd_ret, &ret, sizeof(ret)) < 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "fd_ret: %s\n", strerror(errno));
    close(fd_ret);

    close(fd_stdout);
    close(fd_stderr);
    return 0;
}
```

And,`reboot.sh`, assume reboot flag will be deleted correctly

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "[`date '+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'`] Wait for the completion of the job."
# echo "check reboot flag file: '$1' ..."
while [ -e "$1" ]; do
    sleep 1
done

echo "[`date '+%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'`] Start the reboot."
sync
sync
sync
/sbin/shutdown -r now
```

Comment: On a completely unrelated not, why don't you use an array for the file descriptors as well?

Comment: Also, I assume that the actual code will call `execl` with an actual argument for the script?

Comment: By the way, in your actual program you *do* open the files? And if you can't write to the files, what errors do you get?

Comment: @Joachim, yes this is my whole actual program source code which I am using. I don't get any errors message, just the files which should be written remains empty. Most time data is written but not always. for above comment about array, I think original developer left it for readability, I am not much sure.

Comment: You can see `fn` is open ed each time for all fds.